# If $u=ax^3+by^3$ and $u$ is harmonic, find values of $a$ and $b$. Also find the harmonic conjugate of $u$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

If $u=ax^3+by^3$ and $u$ is harmonic, find values of $a$ and $b$. Also find the harmonic conjugate of $u$.

I could not find any confirmation regarding this solution of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the domain $D \ne \emptyset$ of $u$ is an open subset of $ \mathbb R^2.$

We have $u_{xx}(x,y)=6ax$ and $u_{yy}(x,y)=6by.$

Then $u$ is harmonic on $D \iff ax+by=0$ for all $(x,y) \in D \iff a=b=0.$